# How to use prevState here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am getting the value of previous state on change and I get the updated 
   state on next click. I am sure that we have to use prevstate here but I am 
   not getting how.

````````````````````````````````````````````````
```````````````````````````````````````````````
 event.currentTarget.name == 'isprivate' ? 
   this.setState({[event.currentTarget.name] : event.currentTarget.value}) 
 : this.setState({[event.target.name] : event.target.value}) 

```````````````````````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````````````````````

How do I use `prevState` here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setState` this way:

```
this.setState((prevState) => prevState.flag? ({ myKey: true}) : ({myKey: false}))
```

Or do whatever else you want with the prevState available when setting the new state.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Not clear. What is this flag and mkey. 
Can you help me with the syntax for my code?

Comment: Sorry, they are just placeholder, you can replace them with whatever keys/properties you'd like